# How to get only value in pymongo instead of ObjectId

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo for my project. Everything is working fine. When I find() in my collection, I am getting:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5f08a8f62239f599569dcc6a'), u'value1': u'pizza'}
```

Instead of this complete field, I just want the value1.
My python code is below:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["db_for_video"]
mycol = mydb["user"]

for x in mycol.find():
    print(x)
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `projection`

```
data = mycol.find({}, {'value1': 1, '_id': 0})

for x in data:
    print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
{'value1': 'pizza'}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working. Although, that value is not clean, I am getting like this {u'value1': u'pizza'}. Why am I getting this extra u' '.?

Comment: can you tell me how to get string from that?

Comment: what exactly are you doing with the above output? it doesn't causes any problems and what version of python are you using

Comment: I converted it into string. Now when I do print(x), I am getting something like this: {"Object1" : "Value1"}{"Object2" : "Value2"}. What I want is an array which contains [value1,value2].

Comment: does the keys different for both objects? it will be easy if you post original output